# Armor from Strength change?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-barbarian

How much armor do you get from Strength? My level 60 barb is on inferno. With all armor removed and no passives that give additional armor I have 187 strength and 215 armor. If I add items that have just strength on them and no armor (like amulets/rings) my armor goes up by more than the strength on the item.
For example I add an amulet with 99 strength and now I have 286 strength and 328 armor. The strength has given me 113 armor?
It seems like strength is giving about 1.14 points of armor per point...

Comment: What other stats does the item have?  If you're using the Barbarian passive for Vit to Armor, that will also affect it.

Answer (score 11):

You have the enchantress as your follower, with the +15% armor buff.

[image: Cropped screenshot of Powered Armor description: "Enchantress buffs herself and her allies, increasing Armor by 15%. Attackers are slowed by 30% for 3 seconds.]

Comment: Good catch.  I hadn't even thought of follower buffs.

Answer (score 1):

Every point of Strength provides one point of Armor.  In the event you are gaining more than this, you are not accounting for something.  Barbarians have [Nerves of Steel](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/barbarian/passive/nerves-of-steel), which allows Vitality to go towards Armor, too.  Are you sure you are accounting for everything the item provides?

Comment: The item only has strength on it and I removed any passive that give armor

Answer (score 0):

The Barbarian is the only class which has strength as its primary stats. Each time you get a point of strength, you increase your damage done by 1%. This is a flat relationship – each extra point of strength equals another % of damage dealt. Each point of strength also gives you 1 armor.